# quiero devolver un error en la respuesta de una api pero lo imprime en la consola, ¿como lo arreglo?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, rest, excepciones

estoy haciendo una api rest (en JAVA con Spring Boot) y quiero trabajar con HandlerException pero me lanza el error en la consola en lugar del cuerpo de la respuesta, por favor si alguien sabe que hago mal que me ayude.

mi controller es el siguiente:

```
package com.alura.foro.aluraforo.controller;

import java.net.URI;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import com.alura.foro.aluraforo.topico.RegistroTopicoDTO;
import com.alura.foro.aluraforo.topico.RespuestaTopicoDTO;
import com.alura.foro.aluraforo.topico.TopicoService;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/topicos")
public class TopicoController {

    @Autowired
    private TopicoService topicoService;
    
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<RespuestaTopicoDTO> crearTopico(@RequestBody @Valid RegistroTopicoDTO datos, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder){
        RespuestaTopicoDTO res = topicoService.crear(datos);

        URI uri = uriComponentsBuilder.path("/topicos/{id}").buildAndExpand(res.id()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(res);
    }
}
```

mi servicio:

```
package com.alura.foro.aluraforo.topico;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.alura.foro.infra.errores.SolicitudInvalidaException;

@Service
public class TopicoService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicoRepository topicoRepository;
    

    public RespuestaTopicoDTO crear(RegistroTopicoDTO datos){
        if(datos == null)
            throw new SolicitudInvalidaException("No se envío nada en el cuerpo.");

        if(topicoRepository.existsByTituloAndMensaje(datos.titulo(), datos.mensaje()))
            throw new SolicitudInvalidaException("Ya existe ese mensaje o titulo, no debe haber duplicados");

        Topico topico = new Topico(datos);
        topicoRepository.save(topico);

        return new RespuestaTopicoDTO(topico);
    }
}
```

y mi tratador de errores:

```
package com.alura.foro.infra.errores;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import jakarta.validation.ValidationException;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class TratadorErrores {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> tratarError404(){
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ErrorValidacionDTO>> tratarError400(MethodArgumentNotValidException e){
        var errores = e.getFieldErrors().stream().map(ErrorValidacionDTO::new).toList();
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errores);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = SolicitudInvalidaException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> errorHandlerSinBody(Exception e){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
    }
    




    private record ErrorValidacionDTO(String campo, String errorM){
        public ErrorValidacionDTO(FieldError error){
            this(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

al ejecutar el post con estos datos (ya los cree una vez, osea que estan en la base de datos):

```
{
  "titulo": "asd",
  "mensaje": "Mensaje de prueba",
  "autor": "Kevin",
  "curso": "Primero"
}
```

en la respuesta me da esto:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-09-20T15:55:12.999+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "path": "/topicos"
}
```

y en la consola me da esto: (lo que deberia mostrar en la respuesta)

```
2023-09-20T13:04:23.837-03:00 ERROR 10300 --- [p-nio-80-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.alura.foro.infra.errores.SolicitudInvalidaException: Ya existe ese mensaje o titulo, no debe haber duplicados] with root cause

com.alura.foro.infra.errores.SolicitudInvalidaException: Ya existe ese mensaje o titulo, no debe haber duplicados
        at com.alura.foro.aluraforo.topico.TopicoService.crear(TopicoService.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.alura.foro.aluraforo.controller.TopicoController.crearTopico(TopicoController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Estoy haciendo un api y tengo una relga de negocio que no me permite guardar en la base de datos duplicados del titulo y texto, cuando eso paso lanzo un error, pero en lugar de mostrarse en la respuesta del request, se muestra en la consola.. y no se como solucuinarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré mi error, en el controller tuve que agregar al declaración throws RuntimeException al método crearTopico y ahi el TratadorErrores maneja el error. así:

```
@PostMapping() @Transactional
public ResponseEntity<RespuestaTopicoDTO> crearTopico(@RequestBody @Valid RegistroTopicoDTO datos, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder) throws RuntimeException{
    RespuestaTopicoDTO res = topicoService.crear(datos);

    URI uri = uriComponentsBuilder.path("/topicos/{id}").buildAndExpand(res.id()).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(res);
}
```

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta que te ha sido más útil cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 1):

El error se esta produciendo en el método crearTopico() pero de forma predeterminada se va a imprmir en la consola:

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<RespuestaTopicoDTO> crearTopico(@RequestBody @Valid RegistroTopicoDTO datos, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder){
    RespuestaTopicoDTO res = topicoService.crear(datos);

    URI uri = uriComponentsBuilder.path("/topicos/{id}").buildAndExpand(res.id()).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(res);
}
```

Lo que debes realizar es manejar la excepción para que retorne el mensaje de error en la respuesta:

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<RespuestaTopicoDTO> crearTopico(@RequestBody @Valid RegistroTopicoDTO datos, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder){
    try {
        RespuestaTopicoDTO res = topicoService.crear(datos);

        URI uri = uriComponentsBuilder.path("/topicos/{id}").buildAndExpand(res.id()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(res);
     } catch (SolicitudInvalidaException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage()); //*Devuelve el mensaje de error la respuesta 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hola, pero no se supone que para eso es el TratadorErrores? para evitar escribir try catch? dandole un HandlerException?

Comment: ahí probe y si funciono.. pero despues yo borro un dato del JSON (al hacer el post) y me da otro error 400 (ya que todos los datos son requerdios y ahi debo hacer lo mismo que me sugeriste, pero ahi ya no es escalable por eso quiero usar el HandlerException pero no se por qué me da error.

Comment: Comentas "pero después yo borro un dato del JSON (al hacer el post) y me da otro error 400", debes asegurar que envías los datos necesarios para realizar la petición.

Comment: si pero en caso de que no lo haga, en la respuesta de la peticion me deberia mostrar el error (diciendome que falta) pero no lo hace en la respuesta, lo hace en la consola, no se si me explico?

Comment: Tienes un manejador de excepciones TratadorErrores, que te recomiendo quitar, ya que la excepción se debe manejar en el controlador.

Comment: No, ahi ya se que era jajaj, tenias razón cuando me decias que era el método crearTopico(), solo le agregue throws RuntimeException para que el error se propague y ahí llega al TratadorErrores y maneja el error